# Why is my after_save callback somehow giving me the object before I changed it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-activejob

I have a strange issue using an active record `after_save` [callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to trigger an [active job](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) in Rails.

I have a model called `Service` with a callback that looks like this:

```
after_save :update_index

def update_index
    UpdateIndexServicesJob.perform_later(self)
end
```

And an active job that looks like:

```
class UpdateIndexServicesJob < ApplicationJob
    queue_as :default
    def perform(service)
        # do stuff here
    end
end
```

Despite using an `after_save` callback, a lot of the time, if i log the `service` inside that job, i get the service as it was *before* i changed it.

This seems like some kind of race condition, but it's super weird!

I'm explicitly passing in `self` from the callback to the job, and `self` always seems to equal the service *after* changes when i log it out.

**What's going on here and how can i fix it?**

(I'm using active job because it is doing some slow background work that the user doesn't need to wait around for. This is local development so i'm just running the jobs in memory at the moment.)

Comment: `after_save` callback is triggered before the changes are submitted to the database (still in transaction). If the job starts before the transaction is finished, the old record is used. Can you use `after_commit`? Or is there a specific reason you use `after_save`? If you can use `after_commit`, does that solve your issue?

Comment: That makes total sense. The job is pulling the service from the database even though you are passing in self.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following?

```
after_save :update_index

def update_index
    UpdateIndexServicesJob.perform_later(self.id)
end
```

and then in job

```
class UpdateIndexServicesJob < ApplicationJob
    queue_as :default
    def perform(service_id)
       service_obj = Service.find_by(id: service_id)
        # do stuff here
    end
end
```

The best practice for jobs arguments is that they should be serializable. Passing around objects to job's `perform` method is not recommended. For more details I would suggest you to take a look at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple. Though that is Sidekiq-specific recommendation I recommend following it in general terms when implementing background jobs with arguments.

Hope that helps. Thanks.